# How to handle macOS dock Quit action in QML app?

Tags: c++, macos, qt, qml

I have a simple `ApplicationWindow` that should prevent quitting by overriding `onClosing` signal. However, when the app is closed from macOS dock, the `onClosing` is not called. How to fix that?

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as Controls1

Controls1.ApplicationWindow {
    id: root
    visible: true

    onClosing: close.accepted = false
}
```

> Qt 5.15.2, macOS 10.14.6

Comment: *"When the app is closed from macOS dock..."* -- Does that mean it works when you close it other ways?

Comment: what you see "window is closed", it may be caused by "onError" or "onTerminal" or some other events , because usually "close" event means the normal exit.

Comment: @NicoNing Yes, it works if closed by clicking with a mouse to "close" icon in the window toolbar, but does not work when closed from the dock.

Comment: Can you provide a complete reproducible example? Your snippet doesn't even show a window in the first place. After adding "visible: true" this behaves exactly the way you want it to behave. Neither the red "X" nor "Quit" from the app's context menu in the dock close the window. Tested on MacOS 10.15.7 and 12.2.1.

Comment: @kqt What is "12.2.1" in your last sentence? Is it a macOS version?

Comment: Yes, those were the two MacOS versions I happened to have booted up at the time. My testing consisted of pasting your QML into a blank Qt Quick Application template as provided by QtCreator, running from QtCreator on the 12.2.1 host, building a deployable app using macdeployqt and finally running that app on another Mac. I have now also tested and confirmed the behaviour on an old MacBook running MacOS 10.13.6.

Comment: @kqt Thanks for confirming. That's very weird since I'm using 10.14.6 where it is not working - that's why I was submitting this question in the first place... Qt 5.12.1. Which Qt version are you using?

Comment: I used Qt 5.15.2, just like you wrote in your question.

Comment: @kqt, ok, the difference was that I'm using QtControls 1.4 that allow system menu. I updated the question.

Comment: Same behaviour as before. Still can't quit the app in any way other than "Force Quit" from the system menu.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle `QApplication`'s `QEvent::Close` (Qt 5.x) or `QEvent::Quit` (Qt 6.x) events.